# nginx proxy_pass using a host with a dynamic IP address

Tags: nginx

Can't seem to get this working.

If I use a fixed hostname in the proxy_pass setting, then it is only correct and working at the time the engine is started.

But if the ip address of the proxy changes after the engine is restarted then the new ip address is never re-resolved to the current IP address.

So I tried the following 'set' with a 'resolver', but that does not work, and the browser reports:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

**This is my server block:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name stats.some-domain.com;

  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  set $rpi http://pi.another-domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass $rpi:88/ui;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

maybe a trailing slash? The proxy_pass will replace the / in the location with /ui, but I suspect /ui is a folder and the rpi is trying to tell your browser to ask for a specific index page and that's causing a loop. Try:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $rpi:88/ui/;
    ...
}
```

Cheers!